# Unable to install Ubuntu Newer than 10.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, 10.04, lenovo

my harddrive just died and after replacing it, I installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS which was available at the time without any problems. 
After installing, I realized that 10.04 was obsolete and downloaded the newer 14.04 LTS, but it just won't install. After booting and reading the disc for a while my laptop just restarted by itself. It didn't even reach the "Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu" page. I've tried using a Bootable USB, with the same result. 
My Laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 0578. Anyone know what could be the cause?

Comment: First thought: Check the boot order in BIOS, it should be 'drive' or 'usb disk' first before HDD.

Comment: You burned it to a DVD? Which OS and which program did you use?

Comment: @Parto: The boot order is fine. The installation process reached the Ubuntu logo, but after that it just suddenly restarted my laptop.

Comment: @Zacharee1: I used the burn to DVD function from the Ubuntu 10.04 that I managed to install before.

Comment: @midori_kaba Use Imgburn on a Windows computer.

Comment: @Zacharee1 just tried that. Still the same result.